# Osmnx: How to retreive info on bus-stop info node, which is part of a highway?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am trying to also show info of OpenStreetMap bus-stop node 439460636 (https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/439460636) which is part of a highway.

I am using Python3 Osmnx

Other POIs all show perfectly. Just not the ones which are not maped as a 'amenity'. (There are more examples)

I am using jupyter notebook for my analysis:

```py
import osmnx as ox

# Retrieve POI shelters
place_name = 'Santa Clara, Santa Clara County, California, USA'
shelter = ox.pois_from_place(place_name, amenities=['shelter'])
cols = ['amenity', 'name', 'element_type', 'shelter_type',
       'building', 'network'
        ]
shelter[cols]
```

```py
cols = ['amenity', 'name','element_type', 'shelter_type',
       'building', 'network'
        ]
shelter[cols].loc[(shelter['shelter_type'] == 'public_transport') ]
```

```py
# Look bus-stop in highway
graph = ox.graph_from_place(place_name)
nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph)
nodes.loc[(nodes['highway'] == 'bus_stop') ]
```

Overpass:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  area[name="Santa Clara, Santa Clara County, California, USA"];
  node(area)["highway"="bus_stop"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

The POI `Kino (439460636)`  is not listed. The shelter right next to the POI is listed. The POI is in the middle of my area, so I do not understand how I can retreive the node info. Can you help?

Comment: [node 439460636](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/439460636) is *not* part of a highway, it just has a `highway=bus_stop` tag. This is just a [tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag) and hasn't really much to do with the [element type](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements). I guess `graph_from_place()` doesn't include bus stops since they aren't really part of the road network. You will probably have to call a different function but unfortunately I'm not familiar with osmnx.

Comment: The fact that `pois_from_place()` only looks for amenities and doesn't accept other keys looks like a design error to me. POIs can have various tags, not just `amenity`. Maybe you can use `overpass_request()` for downloading POIs.

Comment: This Overpass query finds the node...:[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  node["highway"="bus_stop"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;

Comment: The was a 'feature' in Osmnx. In Nov chesterharvey created an update, which does not seem to be part of the standard yet. Manually replaced the file and it now works. https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/116#issuecomment-439577495

Comment: Great! I guess you can post this as an answer to your question.

Comment: This functionality to generalize the pois module to work with all points of interest was added to OSMnx's master branch in https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/pull/449 It will appear in the next release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manually update Osmnx with the file linked in this post from chesterharvey. https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/116#issuecomment-439577495
 Final testing of feature still incomplete!

```py
import osmnx as ox

# Specify the name that is used to seach for the data
place_name = "Santa Clara, Santa Clara County, California, USA"

tags = {
    'amenity':True,
    'leisure':True,
    'landuse':['retail','commercial'],
    'highway':'bus_stop',
}

all_pois = ox.pois_from_place(place=place_name, tags=tags)
```

```py
all_pois.loc[(all_pois['highway'] == 'bus_stop')]
```

Comment: The functionality to generalize the pois module to work with all points of interest was added to OSMnx's master branch in https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/pull/449 It will appear in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality as [been added](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.pois.pois_from_place) to OSMnx as of v0.13.0. It generalizes the POIs module to query using a `tags` dict instead of an `amenities` list. It removes the `amenities` parameter from all POI functions. The `tags` dict accepts key:value pairs of the form:

1. 'tag' : True (use bool to retrieve all items with `tag`)
2. 'tag' : 'value' (use string to retrieve all items with `tag` = `value`)
3. 'tag' : ['value1', 'value2', etc] (use list to retrieve all items with `tag` equal to either `value1` or `value2` etc.

Usage examples of the new POI querying functionality:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
tags = {'amenity' : True,
        'landuse' : ['retail', 'commercial'],
        'highway' : 'bus_stop'}
gdf = ox.pois_from_place(place='Piedmont, California, USA', tags=tags)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with footprints I think:

```
#point of interests around an aread
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
import requests

#returns polygon or coordinates of poi
#point = (59.912390, 10.750584)
#amn = ["bus_station",'waste_transfer_station'] #["bus_station",'waste_transfer_station']
#points of interest/amenities we can use: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:amenity
def get_interest_points(long,lat,dist,amn[]):
    point = (long, lat)
    gdf_points = ox.pois_from_point(point, distance=dist, amenities=amn)
    return gdf_points[["amenity", "geometry"]]

#Get bus buildings, distance in meter 400 is minimum
#returns polygon of building
def get_buildings(long,lat,dist):
    point = (long, lat)
    gdf = ox.footprints.footprints_from_point(point=point, distance=dist,footprint_type='buildings')
    return gdf["geometry"]

#Get bus, tram or subway
#type = "bus" or "tram" or "subway"
#, distance in meter 400 is minimum
#returns polygon of stop
def get_buildings(long,lat,dist,type):
    point = (long, lat)
    gdf = ox.footprints.footprints_from_point(point=point, distance=dist,footprint_type=type)
    return gdf["geometry"]
```